# How to plot interactive draw-able image using matplotlib in Google Colab?

Tags: matplotlib, mouse, draw, interactive, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to plot an interactive image which will let me draw lines in output of Google Colab Notebook. I tried using the below code. It's working fine in my local Jupyter Notebook but its not working in Google colab.

Can anyone suggest any workaround on this?

Also tried to add `%matplotlib inline`, but it showed the still image.

```
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
%pylab notebook 
%matplotlib inline
#This is needed for plot widgets

class Annotator(object):
    def __init__(self, axes):
        self.axes = axes

        self.xdata = []
        self.ydata = []
        self.xy    = []
        self.drawon = False

    def mouse_move(self, event):
        if not event.inaxes:
            return

        x, y = event.xdata, event.ydata
        if self.drawon:
            self.xdata.append(x)
            self.ydata.append(y)
            self.xy.append((int(x),int(y)))
            line = Line2D(self.xdata,self.ydata)
            line.set_color('r')
            self.axes.add_line(line)

            plt.draw()

    def mouse_release(self, event):
        # Erase x and y data for new line
        self.xdata = []
        self.ydata = []
        self.drawon = False

    def mouse_press(self, event):
        self.drawon = True


img = np.zeros((28,28,3),dtype='uint8')

fig, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(3,3))
axes.imshow(img)
plt.axis("off")
plt.gray()
annotator = Annotator(axes)
plt.connect('motion_notify_event', annotator.mouse_move)
plt.connect('button_release_event', annotator.mouse_release)
plt.connect('button_press_event', annotator.mouse_press)

axes.plot()

plt.show()
```

I expect the output to be Interactive in Google Colab just like Jupyter notebook in my PC, but the output is still image and nothing can be drawn over it.

Comment: The docs contain [several interactive examples for Altair and plotly](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/charts.ipynb#scrollTo=beTgCbVa_wFA). (Not sure what's required for matplotlib.)

Comment: I don't think Google Colab has support for any of the interactive backends (like %matplotlib notebook, or %matplotlib ipympl). Jupyter notebook or jupyterhub may be better suited for that case.

Comment: Thanks, @BobSmith but I need the interactive output in Colab, which I guess is not possible.

Comment: Hi @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, I want to leverage Colab GPU for taining my model. And If Jupyter notebook or jupyterhub can only provide interactive backends. Can you please suggest how I can connect the trained model of Colab with the Jupyter notebook in order to use `matplotlib`.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to mounted colab with a directory in Google Drive. You can try:

```
fig = plt.figure()
fig.savefig("your_file_name.png")

from IPython.display import Image
Image("your_file_name.png")
```